# nodeJS throwing "Cannot find module" error in one of routes js file

Tags: node.js

I am trying to import one of  model js file as module in one of the routes js file.It is throwing error ""Cannot find module" .But same thing worked well when importing same model file in app.js .Is there any difference here?Can we import  modules only in app.js

using express version : 3.2.6

### modulejs content

```
module.exports.list = function(req, res){

    Movie.find(function(err, movies) {
        if (err){
              return err;
          }
          else{
              return JSON.stringify(movies);
          }
    });

};
```

---

### routes js content

```
var model = require('./model/movie');

exports.listMovies = function(req, res){

      res.render('listMovies', { title: 'test'});
};
```

### error stack:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './model/movie'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: Check the file path because the path needs to be relative to the importing file.

Comment: Thanks Faris..Able to fix it by importing as:                                             var model = require('../model/movieModel');